# User name dissapeared from login screen

Tags: login, login-screen, username

I have Ubuntu 16.04 which is used to host Nextcloud server.
After computer restart my user name is no longer listed on the Ubuntu start page. The only available options are user name which is equal to my hostname and Guest account.
If I press Alt+Ctrl+F1 I can login in with my user name and password but there is an error message: "No directory, logging in with Home=/"

From what I can see all my data is still there.

I don't have much experience with Ubuntu so more detailed instructions how to get my username back to login page will be greatly appreciated.

If any additional information is needed please let me know.

Comment: What happened before this as it seems your home directory is gone, Perhaps you changed your username or so?

Comment: Thank you George.  I checked in recovery mode and folder /home/my-username exists and all files are there. Are you refering to that folder?

Comment: I checked in recovery mode and folder /home/my-username exists and all files are there. Are you referring to that folder?  I tried sudo chown username: /home/username and I got message: "Read-only file system". The same happens if I use chmod command in recovery mode as a root user. Do you know how I could make restore read/write properties or should I make backup of my home folder from recovery console and reinstall everything. I have Nextcloud data & database backups. Can I do anything from live Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry a bit busy. You need to first mount it `rw` with `mount -o remount,rw /` in recovery mode. And don't understand `/home/my-username` and `/home.username`, do you have two different usernames?

Comment: I have only one username. Sorry that was my typing mistake at 3:am. I'll try your advice after work. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I was following instructions in this discussion to setup Nexcloud database automatic backup.
[link] (https://help.nextcloud.com/t/backup-nextcloud-with-seperate-data-folder-and-the-database/5841/8)
Everything was working nicely until the last step where they suggested to secure config file:
'chmod 0600 ~/.my.cnf'  I think that instead of doing that I locked my home folder.

Comment: If so then mount your file system as I earlier suggested then change the permissions for `home` to `chmod 755 /home/$USER`, don't add `-R` and please check your syntax before hitting the enter key!

Comment: Ok I have posted an answer glad it got fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you change you `/home` directory permissions to something unsavoury, so let's fix that using two steps:

1. Remount `/` in `rw` mode from recovery mode:

   - Enter recovery mode from grub menu and mount the file system

     ```
     mount -o remount, rw /
     ```
2. Change the folder permissions to `755`:

   ```
   chmod 755 /home/$USER
   ```

   - Please don't add the `-R` option when using the `chmod` command
3. Reboot